# Chart JS Zoom Plugins not working when chart data label plugins

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

Try to use the Chart Js zoom and ChartDatalabels at same time in angular but return the from index All declarations of 'PluginOptionsByType' must have identical type parameters

I tried bleow attached code
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
Chart.register( ChartDataLabels)
Chart.register(zoomPlugin);

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deleteconfirmdialog',
  templateUrl: './deleteconfirmdialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deleteconfirmdialog.component.scss']
})
export class DeleteconfirmdialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  canvas: any;
  ctx: any;
  @ViewChild('chartCanvas') myCanvas!: ElementRef;
  chart:any;
  chartConfig= {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data 1',
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56]
        },
        {
          label: 'Data 2',
          data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          wheel: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          pinch: {
            enabled: true
          },
          mode: 'xy',
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        // Enable data labels
        datalabels: {
          color: '#fff',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.ctx = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
     let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx,{
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Data 1',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56]
          },
          {
            label: 'Data 2',
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
       
        plugins: {
          // Enable data labels
          datalabels: {
            color: '#fff',
            font: {
              weight: 'bold'
            }
          },
          zoom: {
            // Enable zooming
            enabled: true,
            // Zooming directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable
            // Eg. 'y' would only allow zooming in the y direction
            mode: 'xy'
          },
        }
      }
     })
  }
 

  constructor() { }
 

}
```

[image]

Version:
Angular:15
chartjs:4.1.1
ng2-Chart:4.0.1
zoom-plugin:2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue (and was following this question for an answer) but it was resolved in a recent update.

Now there is a new (different) issue with the latest Chart.js (4.2.1), either with the zoom or annotation plugin (I use both).

I think it is simply the case that updates can leave the main package out of step with the plugins, and we simply have to have patience with the developers (or contribute ourselves!). The trick seems to be identifying a working set of packages and taking care with upgrade paths from there, trying them out and reverting if issues exist. Of course, this does make it difficult to get started, if there is no known working combination to start from. Most recently, a working combination has been Chart.js 4.2.0 with chartjs-plugin-zoom 2.0.0 and chartjs-plugin-annotation 2.1.2.

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/pull/752 for Zoom, The same should be done in the datalabels

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. I resolved this using a hack. In tsconfig.json add skipLibChek: true.  This is not a permanent solution. This resolved my issue

Comment: `"compilerOptions": { "skipLibCheck": true }`